# Scroll background-image / performance

Tags: javascript, css

I use the following Javascript to animate my body background-image (it's a pattern):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var step = 1;
var current = 0;

function scrollBG(){
    current += step;
    if (current == 450){ current = 0; }
    $('.pattern').css('background-position','center '+current+'px');
};

setInterval(scrollBG, 100);

});
```

It works fine but it causes heavy CPU load.

Any suggestions?

Thanks :)

Comment: You could try using new css3 transitions.
However, this is more a question for codereview, not stackoverflow

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion! I tried it using the CSS3 animation but the CPU is as busy as before. PS: Never heard about codereview, sorry for posting it here :)

Comment: I would probably use an absolutely positioned div for the back ground and then move that div. The reason you are getting high CPU is that the browser is re-rendering the whole background every time, with the div it only has to change the position.